# How to create a custom parameter decorator to get the user from request?

Tags: typescript, express, typescript-decorator

In my express.js app I have the following endpoint where I get the user from request like this:

```
@Put('/:_id')
async update (@Request() req: express.Request) {
  // @ts-ignore
  const user  = req.user;
  ....
}
```

I want to create a custom Parameter Decorator to get the user like this `@GetUser user` and my endpoint to look like the below example:

```
@Put('/:_id')
async update (@GetUser user: any) {
  // Here I can use the user object 
  ....
}
```

I already discovered that I can create a custom Parameter Decorator using the following code:

```
export function GetUser(
  target: Object,
  propertyKey: string,
  parameterIndex: number
) {
  console.log(`Decorating param ${parameterIndex} from ${propertyKey}`);
 }
```

How I can get the `request` in this custom Parameter Decorator in order to extract the `user`?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who went down the same road as I did, I discovered that the `@Request` decorator accepts optional parameters.

Here you can find the Github issue: https://github.com/serhiisol/node-decorators/issues/27

All you need to do is to specify the parameter name (in my case `user`) in the @Request decorator like in the below example:

```
@Put('/:_id')
async update (@Request('user') user: UserType) {
  ....
}
```